# How to make api request with callback as argument in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, npm, callback

I want to use method getPlayers(callback) which is defined as:
**getPlayers(callback)**
callback - Required. Called with an object of players
players - An object containing all the players connected to the server, with their name as the key
Retrieve all players connected to the server.
Here is the link to complete module for further details :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/hltv-livescore#getplayerscallback

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use it and access the data, you'll need to do something like this:

```
getPlayers(function(players) {
    // Here your players will be available
    console.log(players)
})
```

Bonus: If you're using ES6, you can use Arrow functions, that are more elegant, like this (single line):

```
getPlayers(players => console.log(players))
```

or (multi line):

```
getPlayers(players => {
    console.log(players)
})
```

You can read more about the async nature of Javascript [here](http://sporto.github.io/blog/2012/12/09/callbacks-listeners-promises/)

Answer (score 1):

If you refer source code of npm package you can see this code 
https://github.com/andrewda/hltv-livescore/blob/master/lib/index.js#L78

```
Livescore.prototype.getPlayers = function(callback) {
callback(self.players);
};
```

You can use getPlayers like this :

```
Livescore.getPlayers(function(players){
 // you will get players here 
});
```